# Does unique on a temporary table column create an index?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a temporary table that I'm using and I have a unique column, example:myID INT UNIQUE

Would this create an index on that column? Or do I have to explicitly create the index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, SQL server will automatically create an index for each additional unique constraint.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177420.aspx

"The Database Engine automatically creates a UNIQUE index to enforce the uniqueness requirement of the UNIQUE constraint....Unless a clustered index is explicitly specified, a unique, nonclustered index is created by default to enforce the UNIQUE constraint."

This is true for temporary tables, which I just verified by testing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does - see this [article here](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/unique.htm):

> UNIQUE Constraints vs. UNIQUE Indexes
>   Many database administrators ask about
>   the difference between a UNIQUE
>   constraint and a UNIQUE index. While
>   you may use different Transact-SQL
>   commands to create them (ALTER
>   TABLE…ADD CONSTRAINT for constraints
>   and CREATE UNIQUE INDEX for indexes),
>   they have the same effect, for the
>   most part. **In fact, when you create a
>   UNIQUE constraint, it actually creates
>   a UNIQUE index on the table.**